# Как перенести алгоритм с турбо паскаля на питон. Посмотрите правильно ли?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pascal

pascal

```
for kv:=2 to n do pn:=pn/kv;

rr:=1/step(2.718,lam/muo);

for kv:=1 to n do

begin rn:=step(lam/muo,kv)/step(2.718,lam/muo);

for i:=1 to kv do rn:=rn/i;

rr:=rr+rn
```

python

```
if kv=2
    pn=pn/kv
    rr=1/(math.e**(lam/muo))
if kv=1
    rn=(lam/muo)/(math.e**(lam/muo))
i=1
    rn=rn/i
rr=rr+rn
```

Comment: Максимально странный код... 2 совершенно бессмысленных отрывка. Чего ждете от ответа?

Comment: Ответ на вопрос в заголовке: посмотрел, неправильно. На паскале цикл, на питоне условие, например. Вы запускали оба этих кода? Подавали им что-нибудь на вход и получали одинаковые результаты?

Comment: А где код на python?

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

for kv in range(2, n+1):
    pn = pn / kv

rr = 1 / math.e ** (lam / muo)

for kv in range(1, n+1):
    rn = (lam / muo) ** kv / math.e ** (lam / muo)
    for i in range(1, kv+1):
        rn = rn / i
    rr = rr + rn                 # или   rr += rn
```

В коде Паскала я вижу `begin`, но не `end`...

В Питоне нет `begin` и `end`, этого достигается *отступами от начала строк.*